# Is the RGB of pixels different between two computers, monitors and laptops? Pyautogui pixel commands don't work the same on others

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm currently creating a script using pyautogui, it intakes pixels and their RGBs, to locate monsters, and trigger things, but for some reason, the script and code I made only work on my PC, if I download the script to another pc, or laptop, and try to use it, it won't work, as if it doesn't recognize the RGB colors of other devices and so it doesn't function.

Also, the devices I used all got the same resolution, 1920x1080

Comment: Asking if "the RGB of pixels" can be different makes no sense. However, as you're talking about game graphics, there are many reasons why a game might render differently on another machine (and thus output different RGB values to begin with). For example, the graphics settings in-game might not be the same, or the video card / driver / driver settings could differ, and there might be OS specific settings as well which influence the video output. You should compare screenshots of an identical game scene from both PCs to ensure that there are no rendering differences between the PCs.

Answer (score 0):

Try some options of [`locateOnScreen`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) like `confidence` or `grayscale`.
Note: You need to have OpenCV installed for the confidence keyword to work.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("image.png", confidence=0.9)
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("image.png", grayscale=True)
```